# Material grid list in Material grid tile possible (nested grids)?

Tags: material-design, angular6, angular-material-6

I guess, it is not allowed to put a material grid in a material grid (nesting grids)?
Can someone please confirm my assumption?
(I am using Angular Material 6.)

```
<mat-grid-list cols="6" gutterSize="32px">
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3">
        left
        <mat-grid-list cols="3" gutterSize="8px">
            <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>

            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="2">2</mat-grid-tile>

            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3">3</mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
    </mat-grid-tile>

    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3">
        right
        <mat-grid-list cols="3" gutterSize="8px">
            <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>

            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="2">5</mat-grid-tile>

            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3">6</mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

The result should be look like this (two different gutter sizes):

[image]

Why do I want this? The design I have to implement has DIFFERENT GUTTER SIZES between the columns :-/ I thought a grid in a grid would be a clever solution, but it doesn't work.

UPDATE:
The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890631/angular-material-nested-grid) does not work, as this is only possible in the older Angular**JS** Material.

Comment: I use display:flex for grid alike display - never liked grid list.

Comment: Maybe the solution you need is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890631/angular-material-nested-grid

Comment: @TiagoNeiva damn I searched for a similar question in stackoverflow but didn't find this, thank you

Comment: No problem , let me know anything else!

Comment: Hello again, maybe here you have what your looking for ? https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples

Comment: @TiagoNeiva no, thanks, the one example there shows one grid with only one and the same gutter size. I need two grids because I need two gutter sizes.

Comment: I see i will try to do some tests here to see if i can get a solution !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying everything I could think of, I came to the conclusion, that **material grid in material grid is not possible** and probably conceptually not meant to work (understandably).

I decided to solve my problem by using a **CSS grid** (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp). This works (so far):

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="fit" gutterSize="32px">
<mat-grid-tile>
    <div class="css-grid">
        <div class="css-grid-tile top-left">
        </div>
        <div class="css-grid-tile top-right">
        </div>
        <div class="css-grid-tile bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-grid-tile>

<mat-grid-tile>
    <div class="css-grid">
        <div class="css-grid-tile top-left">
        </div>
        <div class="css-grid-tile top-right">
        </div>
        <div class="css-grid-tile bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

```
.css-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 67%; // two columns
  grid-template-rows: 33% 67%; // two rows
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  .css-grid-tile {
    &.top-left {
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
    }

    &.top-right {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;
    }

    &.bottom {
      grid-column: 1 / 3;
    }
  }
}
```